# How to send a data to PHP page when clicking on a Link?

Tags: php

I have several links in an HTML page (say some 100 - 120). What I exactly need is to send different data to another PHP page (say display.php) when I click on each link. I tried a pathetic method,

```
<form action="display.php" method="post"> // or GET
   <input type="hidden" name ="data" value="Data1" />
   <input type="submit" value="Link 1" />
</form>`  
.  
.  
.  

<form action="display.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name ="data" value="Data120" />
   <input type="submit" value="Link 120" />
</form>
```

Is there any simple way to reduce the usage of these 120 forms?

Comment: What's the purpose of these links? Why not query parameters? `display.php?data=Data1`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can put data directly on the href of your  tag.
Ex:

```
<a href="./display.php?data=Data1&data2=Data120">Click here</a>
```

Then in your display.php file :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["data"]) && isset($_GET["data2"]))
    {
        $data = $_GET["data"];
        $data2 = $_GET["data2"];
    }
?>
```

Here you go.

Answer (score 1):

yes sure 
try to use  tags with id's

```
<a href="display?data=data1">link1</a>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form action='display.php' method='post'>
  <input type="submit" value="Link 1" name='1' onclick='setHidden(this)'/>
  <input type="submit" value="Link 2" name='2' onclick='setHidden(this)'/>
  <input type="submit" value="Link 3" name='3' onclick='setHidden(this)'/>
  <input type="submit" value="Link 4" name='4' onclick='setHidden(this)'/>

  <input type="hidden" id='data' name ="data" value="" />
</form>
```

// Javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function setHidden( key)
  {
       var dataStr='Data';
       dataStr+=key.name;

        document.getElementById('data').value=dataStr;  
  }
</script>
```

then in display.php file

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['data']))
   {
      $data=$_POST['data'];

      echo $data;
   }  
?>
```